# How to create NTLM Token in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ntlm, node-soap, ntlm-authentication

I am trying to access a wsdl which is password protected and uses ntlm authentication strategy.

```js
var wsdl_options= {
ntlm: true,
username: "Username",
password: "Password",
domain:'domain'
}
```

I am using node-soap but it isn't working I am trying to pass the above object in the soap.createClient() method in the options object but its not working so I am trying to create a token and pass it as a header but I am unable to understand how to create ntlm token in node.js.